# How can I set the Cache-Control when using Write-S3Object?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-powershell

I am using Windows Powershell for AWS and I have tried the following:

```
Write-S3Object 
   -BucketName 'user-ab-staging' 
   -KeyPrefix 'content/css' 
   -Folder 'content/css' 
   -SearchPattern '*.css' 
   -Metadata @{"Cache-Control" = "Value"}
   -CannedACLName PublicRead
```

It gives me a very strange error and only tries to load one css file:

```
Uploaded 1 object(s) to bucket 'user-ab-staging' from 'C:\g\ab-user\WebUserApp\content\css' with keyprefix
 'content/css'
Write-S3Object :
At line:1 char:1
+ Write-S3Object `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...eS3ObjectCmdlet:WriteS3ObjectCmdlet) [Write-S3Objec
   t], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.S3.WriteS3ObjectCmdlet
```

Can anyone help tell me what is wrong with this and how I can set the Cache data for the object when I am **using Write-S3Object** and the **Powershell extension for AWS**?

Comment: First check if the permission setting is right in s3 bucket or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set up some test folders locally and on S3 and can replicate this issue exactly.

After some digging/experimenting... it relates to the `CannedACLName` parameter. The files upload successfully when removing that parameter.

This [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-s3-upload-object.html) says that the correct option to use is `PublicRead`, but the correct option is actually `public-read`. After making that change, I was able to successfully write all objects in the specified folder.

Your updated code would look like this:

```
Write-S3Object 
   -BucketName 'user-ab-staging' 
   -KeyPrefix 'content/css' 
   -Folder 'content/css' 
   -SearchPattern '*.css' 
   -Metadata @{"Cache-Control" = "Value"}
   -CannedACLName public-read
```

If you need to use any of the other ACL options in the future, I would recommend trying from [this list in the ACL documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) instead. I've tested a few of the options available there and they've all worked.

Answer (score 4):

Note that using the `-Metadata` argument for Write-S3Object sets the "x-amz-meta-cache-control" metadata property. If you want to set the "Cache-Control" (as for HTTP response headers for S3 website hosting), use this argument pattern instead:

```
-HeaderCollection @{"Cache-Control" = "Value"}
```